# WCF Excepción: No se puede escribir datos de en la conexión de transporte: Se ha forzado la interrupción de una conexión existente por el host remoto

Tags: webservice, wcf

Estoy desarrollando una Aplicación WCF que se conecta de forma remota a un Reloj Checador, al usar funciones que devuelven un registro o unos cientos (300 o 400) funciona correctamente, pero al usar una función que extrae algo mas de 8 mil registros, manda el siguiente error:

> > System.Net.WebException   HResult=0x80131509   Message=Se ha terminado la conexión: Una conexión que se esperaba que se mantuviera
> >     activa fue cerrada por el servidor.   Source=System.Web.Services
> >     StackTrace:    at
> >     System.Web.Services.Protocols.WebClientProtocol.GetWebResponse(WebRequest
> >     request)    at
> >     System.Web.Services.Protocols.HttpWebClientProtocol.GetWebResponse(WebRequest
> >     request)    at
> >     System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.Invoke(String
> >     methodName, Object[] parameters)    at
> >     Test.ZKTecoClient.ZKTecoService.DispHorariosListTodo(Int32 machineID,
> >     Boolean machineIDSpecified, EmpleadoDisp[] _empleadosList) in
> >     C:\Users\jerry\source\repos\wcfZKTeco_Service\Test\Web
> >     References\ZKTecoClient\Reference.cs:line 351    at
> >     Test.Program.Main(String[] args) in
> >     C:\Users\jerry\source\repos\wcfZKTeco_Service\Test\Program.cs:line 47
>
> Inner Exception 1: IOException: No se puede escribir datos de en la
>   conexión de transporte: Se ha forzado la interrupción de una conexión
>   existente por el host remoto.
>
> Inner Exception 2: SocketException: Se ha forzado la interrupción de
>   una conexión existente por el host remoto

Poniendo punto de interrupción en la función del WCF, antes de devolver los datos, sí obtiene el listado de "Entidades", pero al salir de esa función para ya devolver los datos es cuando sucede este error.

El Web Config del WCF es este:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
        <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
        <section name="entityFramework"
          type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089"
          requirePermission="false"/>
    </configSections>

  <appSettings>
    <add key="aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext" value="true"/>
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.6.1"/>
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.6.1"/>
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding closeTimeout="00:25:00" openTimeout="00:25:00" receiveTimeout="00:25:00"
          sendTimeout="00:25:00" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxBufferSize="2147483647"
          maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" transferMode="Streamed"
          messageEncoding="Text">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="0"
            maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="0" />
          <security mode="None" />
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="false" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
          <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="10000000" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <protocolMapping>
        <add binding="basicHttpBinding" scheme="http" />
    </protocolMapping>    
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true"/>
  </system.serviceModel>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
    <!--
        To browse web app root directory during debugging, set the value below to true.
        Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing web app folder information.
      -->
    <directoryBrowse enabled="true"/>
  </system.webServer>
  <entityFramework>
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer"/>
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>

</configuration>
```

Y este es el de la Aplicación Cliente (Estoy haciendo pruebas con una aplicación de Consola):

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <configSections>
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false"/>
    </configSections>
    <startup> 
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.8" />      
    </startup>
    <entityFramework>
        <providers>
            <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer"/>
        </providers>
    </entityFramework>
    <system.serviceModel>      
      <behaviors>
        <serviceBehaviors>
          <behavior>
            <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="10000000" />
            <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
          </behavior>
        </serviceBehaviors>
      </behaviors>
      <bindings>
        <basicHttpBinding>
          <binding closeTimeout="00:25:00" openTimeout="00:25:00" receiveTimeout="00:25:00"
            sendTimeout="00:25:00" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxBufferSize="2147483647"
            maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" transferMode="Streamed"
            messageEncoding="Text">
            <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="0"
              maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="0" />
            <security mode="None" />
          </binding>
        </basicHttpBinding>
      </bindings>
    </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

Las Funciones del Web Service (WCF) que hacen la conexión al Reloj Checador, las tengo también en una simple DLL, y al usar la aplicación cliente con referencia a esta DLL, es decir, usar la DLL directamente y no con el Web Service, devuelve los datos sin problema, pero con el Web Service falla, por qué podría ser?

Answer (score 1):

El problema era que la "Entidad" que intentaba obtener tiene varias propiedades, Año, Mes, Dia, Hora, Minuto, Segundo y una propiedad solo lectura "Fecha", tenía una función que "construía" el valor de la propiedad Fecha, pero me dí cuenta que no se ejecutaba dicha función, lo único que hice fué eliminar esa función y modificar la propiedad "Fecha" como lectura y escritura... y ya funcionó sin problema... aunque aún no sé por qué esto provocaba el error.

Answer (score 0):

Se me ocurre que puede ser, la etiqueta `TransaccionFlow="true"` con este atributo la llamada se caera luego de enviar la respuesta. Todo depende de como tenes configurado el servicio. Pero viendo el basicHttpBinding no creo que tengas sesiones en el servicio.

```
 <binding closeTimeout="00:25:00" openTimeout="00:25:00" receiveTimeout="00:25:00"
          sendTimeout="00:25:00" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxBufferSize="2147483647"
          maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" transferMode="Streamed"
          messageEncoding="Text" TransactionFlow="true">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="0"
            maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="0" />
          <security mode="None" />
```